# How to filter vector elements relative to other ones?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, filter

I a vector of vectors, each representing a a set (in the mathematical sense). For example:

```
{{1, 3}, {4, 9, 14}, {1, 3}, {1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16}, {1, 3, 9}, {4, 9, 17, 22}}
```

I want to make the most efficient C++ possible function capable of filtering (in place, if possible) the vector in order to remove every item that contains another.

For example, here:

- `{1, 3}` is contained by `{1, 3}` and `{1, 3, 9}`
- `{4, 9, 14}` is contained by `{1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16}`

The resulting vector would then be:

```
{{1, 3}, {4, 9, 14}, {4, 9, 17, 22}}
```

As I'm beginning with C++ don't really have any clue of how to do this efficiently. I found, on other answers here, the erase / remove idiom, which doesn't seem to be very appropriate here, except by passing erase a closure as predicate. Which doesn't seem really idiomatic in C++.

Please note that keeping the original ordering doesn't matter, nor does the ordering of values inside each set.

Comment: If you keep each vector in sorted order, then you should be able to do that fairly efficiently.

Comment: {1, 3, 9} or {1, 3, 18}?

Comment: I'm thinking you could do what Kerrek has said: sort the vectors, and then use something like std::unique with an appropriate comparison function.

Comment: Sort each vector, and then sort the whole collection lexicographically. Once that's done, you can traverse and only need to look forward to see if there's proper containment.

Comment: In your real application do you store integers inside the sets or is it some other class?

Comment: I'll try filtering with `std::unique` first, thanks. However, about @KerrekSB idea (which I had, at first), I don't see any simple / idiomatic way to filter the vector that way while traversing it. Nor did I find any answer pointing in that direction here. Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: directly inside the vectors.

Comment: @KerrekSB Still O(n^2), isn't it?

Comment: "Contains" is a partial ordering. Perform topological sort, then discard everything but the leaves. Topological sort is linear in the number of vertices plus the number of edges; in your case, the number of edges could be quadratic (e.g. `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3} ...}` ), so the algorithm is quadratic worst case, but could be better if the graph is more sparse.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wouldn't you have to do O(n^2) work just to determine the edges?

Comment: Igor is right, a simple "lexicographical" sort won't work because {4, 9, 14} would be after {1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16} even though {1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16} contains {4, 9, 14}

Comment: I'm trying (hard) to do this by lexicographically sorting each vector of same size. This *should* work.

Comment: I don't think it will work. Consider: {1, 3}, {1, 6}, {1, 3, 9}

Comment: @KevinCadieux : Yes. This is already sorted according to what I said. `{1, 3, 9}` will be removed, and that's what I want. The base assumption is : if a vector `V1` contains another vector `V2`, then `|V1| >= |V2|`, and `|V1| = |V2| <=> V1 = V2`. Which IMO makes the solution quite simple.

Comment: Yes but it won't work (only) with std::unique in that case because {1,3} and {1,3,9} are not adjacent. For a given set of numbers, you will have to check all the sets that have more elements.

Comment: @KevinCadieux : that's true. But I don't really see any better (and simple) solution. Still better than nothing...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37959/discussion-between-kevin-cadieux-and-pierre)

Comment: Why not use std::set instead of vector and the corresponding set algorithms set_union, set_intersection, set_intersection, set_difference?

Comment: @koodawg This does have to work with legacy code using vectors. Wouldn't `std::set` imply some overhead given that the only operation I do need to do on these is well covered by `std::includes`, taking advantage of the fact that these vectors are guaranteed to be sorted by nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what I learnt so far, thanks to your *very* helpful comments, the solution I came up with is:

```
struct std::vector<size_t> colset;

bool less_colsets(const colset& a, const colset& b) {
  return a.size() < b.size();
}

void sort_colsets(std::list<colset>& l) {
  l.sort(less_colsets);
}

void strip_subsets(std::list<colset>& l) {
  sort_colsets(l);
  for (std::list<colset>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) {
    std::list<colset>::iterator j = next(i, 1);
    while (j != l.end()) {
      if (includes((*j).begin(), (*j).end(), (*i).begin(), (*i).end())) {
        j = l.erase(j);
      }
      else {
        ++j;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I replaced the outermost `std::vector` by `std::list` which is much more optimised for element removal anywhere.

This seems to work as expected, though I'd need some more tests to prove this. <s>The next step will be to use a more efficient comparison function than `includes`, which would take into account the fact that each vector is lexically ordered (which the program guarantees). I'll try this tomorrow.</s>

**Edit**: Looks like `std::includes` already takes care of this fact. YAY!

Thanks everybody.

Comment: `std::includes` requires that both ranges be ordered, and is using this property. Its complexity is linear in the total length of two ranges.

Comment: I didn't see that property... Seems even better than I thought then. Great!