# Segmentation fault when trying to remove element from a list

Tags: c++, algorithm, segmentation-fault

In order to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985629/how-to-filter-vector-elements-relative-to-other-ones) I have, I wrote this little piece of code:

```
for (std::list<std::vector<int>>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) {
  for (std::list<std::vector<int>>::iterator j = next(i, 1); j != l.end(); ++j) {
    if (includes((*j).begin(), (*j).end(), (*i).begin(), (*i).end())) {
      l.erase(j++);
    }
  }
}
```

The basic idea is, given an element of the list, to remove elements from the rest of the list that matches some criteria (in this case, a containment relation).

Executing this triggers a segmentation fault, which I can't understand. Can anyone give me a clue about this?

Comment: Don't mix `for`-increment with container mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is right, thanks. The corrected code is:

```
for (std::list<colset>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) {
  std::list<colset>::iterator j = next(i, 1);
  while (j != l.end()) {
    if (includes((*j).begin(), (*j).end(), (*i).begin(), (*i).end())) {
      j = l.erase(j);
    }
    else {
      ++j;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you code was still not correct. I modified it. You can't use `l.erase(j++)`. You need to do `j = l.erase(j)`

Comment: @MarkLakata Thanks! However, the code as I first wrote it worked with my test case. The comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it) were very helpful at understanding why I shouldn't do this.

Comment: The problem with "Undefined Behavior" means that you can't predict if it is going to work or not :).  Once you do `l.erase(j)` on `j`, then `j` points to junk, and `j++` is UB.

Comment: That's the postfix increment, which first increments j and then does an erase on the previous value. There is no UB involved. The code is actually rather idiomatic, at least for C++98, because there erase() returned void (at least for some containers). Using postfix increment in the else-branch is useless though, although harmless.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the precision. As I do need to increment the vector in the `else` branch, I don't really get your point regarding this. Are you suggesting that `std::advance` would be more appropriate?

Comment: No, advance() is not needed. However, in the else branch you can use `++j` or `j++`, but the former is potentially faster because it doesn't have to create a temporary for storing the previous value. As a general rule, use the prefix increment unless you need postfix increment.